# How can we declare and use class in react-native functional component without extending it with React.Component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I just want to create a class in the function component. Declare the variable inside that class and use it in the function component.

Here is my `app.js`:

```js
const App = () => {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   const increaseCount = () => {
     setCount(count+1)
   }
   return (
     <View>
       <Pressable onPress={() => {increaseCount()}} >
         <Text>Increase</Text>
       </Pressable>
       <Text>{count}</Text>
     </View>
   )
}
```

I just want the same functionality with the class.
I repeat with **CLASS** not **CLASS COMPONENT.**

Comment: What part do you want to be implemented with a class? Also, why define a class inside a functional component. You can define it outside too right?

Comment: Ask about the problem you’re trying to solve rather than how to implement the solution you think you need. You don’t need to define a class inside the functional component.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to create a class in the function component. Declare the variable inside that class and use it in the function component.

With comments, this satisfies your request:

```
const App = () => {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   const increaseCount = () => {
     setCount(count+1)
   }

   // I just want to create a class in the function component
   class Example {
     //  Declare the variable inside that class
     static message = 'hello'
   }
 
   // and use it in the function component
   const message = Example.hello;

   return (
     <View>
       <Pressable onPress={() => {increaseCount()}} >
         <Text>Increase</Text>
       </Pressable>
       <Text>{count}</Text>
     </View>
   )
}
```